# База данных перестаёт выдавать информацию

Tags: python, telebot, pymysql

Пишу телеграмм бота на PyTelegramBotAPI
База данных на reg ru
Когда тестирую на компе , всё работает. Загружаю бота на сервер VPS (тоже на reg ru), всё тоже работает
На след день бот просто не может ничего достать из БД. Просто возвращает пустой список
Запускаю бота с другим Токеном у себя на компе. Всё работает
Может кто-то сталкивался ?

Перезагружаю бота, всё работает. Через день опять такая же ситуация, просто пустой список достаёт из БД

Comment: Может дело в том, как с курсорами работа обстоит?